# Loop in the loop not shows all results

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have two documents. 
One is XML:

```xml
<sdl>
<group>
    <trans-unit id="57628711-51bd-4e2c-811c-7fa7a5a1cac0">
        <source><g id="67">G_Source_1</g>Source_1</source>
        <seg-source><mrk mtype="seg" mid="4">Seg_Source_1</mrk></seg-source>
        <target><mrk mtype="seg" mid="4"><g id="67">G_Target_1</g>Target_1</mrk></target>
    </trans-unit>
</group>
<group>
        <trans-unit id="7da4f54e-1fa9-46b3-846e-e7745840dcd8">
            <source><g id="970">G_Source_6.1</g>Source_6<g id="971">G_Source_6.2</g></source>
            <seg-source><mrk mtype="seg" mid="921">Seg_Source_6</mrk></seg-source>
            <target><mrk mtype="seg" mid="921"><g id="970">G_Target_6.1</g>Target_6<g id="971">G_Target_6.2</g></mrk></target>
        </trans-unit>
</group>
</sdl>
```

And another is a tab separated .txt file.

```
G_Source_1  G_Target_1
G_Source_6.1    G_Target_6.1
G_Source_6.1    G_Target_6.2
```

This code should comapre all text from `<g>` tags from XML file with all text from 1st column of the TXT file.
And puts the all this results.

I have following code for this:

```ruby
glo = File.open(glo_file)
sdlxlff = Nokogiri::XML(open(sdlxlff_file))
sdlxlff.remove_namespaces!
sdlxlff_content = sdlxlff.xpath("//trans-unit")
sdlxlff_content.each do |product| 
  source_sdl = product.xpath("source/g").text
  target_sdl = product.xpath("target//g").text
  mid = product.xpath("target//mrk/@mid")
  glo.each_line do |line|
    content_glo = line.split("\t",2)
    source_glo = content_glo[0]
    target_glo = content_glo[1]
    if source_sdl == source_glo
      puts "same"
      puts source_glo
      puts source_sdl
      puts mid
    end
  end
end
```

But there is a result only for 1st string of XML:

```
same
G_Source_1
G_Source_1
4
```

Could you please point to my issue.
Now my code compare only 1st `<g>` tag and skipped all the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that when there is more than one node matching your `xpath`, calling `text` on it will concat all the results together:

```
sdlxlff_content.xpath('//trans-unit/target//g').text
# => "G_Target_1G_Target_6.1G_Target_6.2"
```

To avoid this, you need to call `text` *on each* element matching:

```
sdlxlff_content.xpath('//trans-unit/target//g').map { |x| x.text }
# => ["G_Target_1", "G_Target_6.1", "G_Target_6.2"]
```

So you can change your code to look something like this:

```
sdlxlff_content.each do |product| 
  source_sdl = product.xpath("source/g").map { |x| x.text }
  target_sdl = product.xpath("target//g").map { |x| x.text }
  mid = product.xpath("target//mrk/@mid")
  glo.each_line do |line|
    content_glo = line.split("\t",2)
    source_glo = content_glo[0]
    target_glo = content_glo[1]
    if source_sdl.any? { |x| x == source_glo }
      puts "same"
      puts source_glo
      puts "#{source_sdl}"
      puts mid
    end
  end
end
```

Output:

```
same
G_Source_1
["G_Source_1"]
4
same
G_Source_6.1
["G_Source_6.1", "G_Source_6.2"]
921
same
G_Source_6.1
["G_Source_6.1", "G_Source_6.2"]
921
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. But I have found an issue.
I not closed file after 1st run of second loop.
After adding glo.close before end of 1st loop. all become working as exoected.

Regards,
Stanislav